# Issue with pairing two seperate file names to a meta variable in nextflow

Tags: groovy, bioinformatics, nextflow

I'm building a data analysis pipeline in nextflow for some sequencing data and am currently adapting it from single to paired end usage. In the single end function I used the following block to pair a meta variable with its respective tag in the fastq file name.

```
ch_id_paired = ch_id_pair.flatMap { meta_list, fastq_list ->
def meta_map = meta_list.collectEntries {
    meta -> [ meta.id.split('_').first(), meta ]

}

def fastq_map = fastq_list.collectEntries {
    fastq -> [ fastq.simpleName.split('_').last(), fastq ]

}

meta_map.collect { k, v -> [ v, fastq_map[k] ] }
}
}
```

it takes a channel that looks like

```
[[[id: id1, single_end:true], [id: id2, single_end:true]], [sample1_id1.fastq, sample2_id2.fastq]]
```

and returns

```
[[[id: id1, single_end:true], sample1_id1.fastq], [[id: id2, single_end:true], sample2_id2.fastq]
```

the second format being needed for downstream processes.

With the new paired end processing the channel looks like:

```
[[[id: id1, single_end:true], [id: id2, single_end:true]], [ forward_sample1_id1.fastq, forward_sample2_id2.fastq, reverse_sample1_id1.fastq, reverse_sample2_id2.fastq]]
```

and only returns the reverse paired as such:

```
[[[id: id1, single_end:true], reverse_sample1_id1.fastq], [[id: id2, single_end:true], reverse_sample2_id2.fastq]
```

instead of the desired:

```
[[[id: id1, single_end:true], forward_sample1_id1.fastq, reverse_sample1_id1.fastq], [[id: id2, single_end:true], forward_sample2_id2.fastq, reverse_sample2_id2.fastq]
```

I initially tried to use the first code format cause it checks by the final '_' in the fastq name so I am unsure why its cutting out the forward sample.

I have more expertise in nextflow rather than groovy functionality and recieved assistance to create the initial block of code so any assistance in how to pair both reads forward and reverse with their meta variable would be greatly appreciated.